# Transfer data of phone with partially broken touchscreen

Tags: samsung, broken-screen, data-transfer

I recently dropped my S7 edge and the bottom half of the screen is now unresponsive (It still displays the image but the touchscreen doesn't work) I'm getting a new phone for christmas so I'm not bothered about repairing the screen. However, I would like to get some photos off it.

The problem however, is that the "approve data transfer" message appears in the broken portion of the screen. Does anyone know a way around this?

*note*
*because the bottom of the screen isn't working for touchscreen I am unable to use the keyboard*

Thanks

Comment: You can try to attach a keyboard via USB or Bluetooth. Mouse also works.